# Automate create same policy to all AWS Accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, terraform

Looking for suggestions on an AWS use case.

I have a lot of accounts in my AWS. 
I am looking to create the same policy in all of my accounts. Now I want to automate it.

1) Can I create any lambda function or cloud formation template or any way to automate the creation of the same policy in all of my accounts even if any new account is created and it needs to add to all existing accounts if it's not there?

2)If possible then how I can get access to lamda function to create policies.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple AWS accounts, you may want to consider using AWS Organizations and Service Control Policies (SCP). The policies are applied at a root level and affect all accounts under that root.

By using organizations, you can get events when account creation is completed and apply any additional changes to the account that you would like by using a Lambda function that receives a CloudWatch event. The event would contain information about the newly created account.

The two options that provided seem to require a lot of manual administrative overhead, but would be happy to answer your concerns. Creating Lambda function which creates policies is done using the SDK. There is an IAM method called "CreatePolicy" which provides this functionality.

Comment: In the second option, Event though I get details of Newly created account details. How I can get access to it?

Comment: Do you mean the creation of IAM roles? 

If so, you can use the AWS SDK with your programming language of choice to automate this: https://aws.amazon.com/tools/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your needs here (and assuming they're still the same after almost 3 years), you might consider using [CloudFormation StackSets instead](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/services-that-can-integrate-cloudformation.html). They allow you to define common resources, including policies, as a CloudFormation template and have that template deployed to every one of the accounts in your organization.

You'll need to [enable trusted access for CloudFormation StackSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/services-that-can-integrate-cloudformation.html#integrate-enable-ta-cloudformation) in your organization AWS account, which will allow it to deploy the stacks to the rest of your organization's accounts.

To create the stack you'll need to:

- Define a CloudFormation template using either CloudFormation directly, or [capturing the synthesized stack from an AWS CDK application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-synth).
- Upload the produced template to a location in S3 that's accessible by your top-level organization account.
- Create the StackSet in the CloudFormation console (or the CLI, CDK, etc). You can either deploy the stack to all accounts or filter by specific accounts or organizational units (OUs).

Once created, the stacks will be automatically deployed to the desired accounts, and kept up to date when the stack is updated. This will require you to define significantly less infrastructure.